# Right Join does not return all the records from right side table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

> Table 1 : assetdetail : itm_id,itm_slno,itm_desc,..
>
> Table 2 : itmtype     : typ_id,typname,..

Table2 Contains 6 different typname.

But when I use right join it returns only 4 records.

[image]

My query is :

```
SELECT a.itm_id,i.typname,a.itm_slno,a.itm_desc,a.itm_class from assetdetail
a right join itmtype i on i.typ_id=a.typ_id where a.itm_id!='234'
and itm_class='XYZ' group by i.typname
```

I need to get all the 6 typename records in the join query.What is the wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 6):

In a `right join`, conditions on the *first* table need to go into the `on` clause, not the `where` clause:

```
SELECT a.itm_id, i.typname, a.itm_slno, a.itm_desc, a.itm_class
from assetdetail a right join
     itmtype i
     on i.typ_id = a.typ_id and a.itm_id <> '234' and a.itm_class = 'XYZ'
group by i.typname;
```

Non-matching rows in the first table have `NULL` values, which fail the comparisons in the `where`.

I would write this as a `left join`, however.  Most people find the logic easier to follow:  keep all rows in the first table, regardless of whether there is a match:

```
SELECT a.itm_id, i.typname, a.itm_slno, a.itm_desc, a.itm_class
from itmtype i left join
     assetdetail a 
     on i.typ_id = a.typ_id and a.itm_id <> '234' and a.itm_class = 'XYZ'
group by i.typname;
```

The conditions remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But your query returns all the typname from itmtype. Condition (a.itm_class = 'XYZ') is not working.I don't know why

Comment: Yes. In practice, RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I need to get only the 6 records with out NULL values.IS there possibilities ?

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi . . . Perhaps you just want an inner join.  You should update your question with sample data as well as desired results.